# Tensor (Einstein) Notation with Mixed Components

Tags: linear-algebra, notation, tensors

I am told that $T'^{\cdot 3}_{2} = a_2^k a_l^3 T'^{\cdot l}_{k}$

$ = a_2^1 a_1^3 T'^{\cdot l}_{1} + ... + a_2^3 a_1^3 T'^{\cdot 3}_{3}$

My confusion is with $a_2^3 a_1^3 T'^{\cdot 3}_{3}$: How can we have $l = 1$ and $l = \cdot 3$? Shouldn't they both be $3$ such that we get $a_2^3 a_3^3 T'^{\cdot 3}_{3}$? After all since we have one $l$ down and the other $l$ up, we are summing over $l$, so shouldn't they both be the same from $1$ to $3$? But in this last case, the solution has them different.

I would greatly appreciate it if people could please take the time to clarify this.

Comment: Yeah, this doesn’t seem right. There should be nine terms total, with $k$ and $l$ replaced by each possible pair of two numbers from $1$ to $3$.

Comment: @EikeSchulte Thanks for the response. So am I correct in thinking that it should be $a_2^3 a_3^3 T'^{\cdot 3}_{3}$?

Comment: I think so. And the first term should also have a $1$ instead of the $l$.

Comment: @EikeSchulte Ok. Thank you very much for the assistance.